# Tina.io CMS not updating content on Vercel

Tags: vercel, tinacms, tina-cms

What I did:

- change .md files

  - Specifically, edit items in a collection that are referenced via `type: 'reference'` in tina config. Note: when I query for cms data using tina client, I do not ask for these collections directly. Rather, these are referenced objects.
- push changes to github
- Vercel automatically builds this successfully
- The live preview url does not reflect changes.  * I would expect it to *
- However, the `/admin` edit mode does correctly display the updated changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can force refresh the tina cms by changing the config file. I added an insignificant change (optional field) and it was able to force tina cloud to update and reflect the changes.